# generating function Homework Question 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This is a HW question

I am asked to find a closed form generating function for $1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0....$
so then $f(x)=x^0+x^1+0x^2+x^3+x^4+0x^5+x^6+x^7+0x^8$

could use some hint or help.

Comment: Try finding it as the difference between two generating functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: See if writing it as follows helps:

$$f(x) = 1 + x + x^{3} +x^{4} + \cdots = ( 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5} + \cdots ) - (x^{2} + x^{5} + x^{8} + \cdots) = \frac{1}{1-x} - x^{2}(1+x^{3}+x^{6}+\cdots)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes I believe I can. Thanks for the quick edit.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: So the answer is $\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x^2}{(1-x^3)}$

Comment: That looks good to me! You could put everything under a common denominator to see if anything simplifies further, but that was what I had in mind. And thanks @MhenniBenghorbal :)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** You can view it as a sum of two simple infinite geometric series.